# Why usort reverts an array when values are equals on PHP prior to 7.0

Tags: php, usort

I'm trying to use usort on an array, and get a different behavior regarding the version of PHP:

```
$arr1 = [
    [
        'points' => 10,
        'date' => 3,
    ],
    [
        'points' => 10,
        'date' => 2,
    ],
    [
        'points' => 10,
        'date' => 1,
    ]
];

usort($arr1, function ($a, $b) {
    if($a['points'] == $b['points']){
      return 0;
    }
    return ($a['points'] < $b['points']) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

This array contains a "date" value, and is ordered DESC on this value, after the usort based on a "points" value, items with the same "points" value are reversed on PHP 5.6, and keep their original order on PHP 7.0...

You may test this online here, with the different PHP versions (please test against PHP 5.6.29 and 7.0.1): http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2715220539623b4b699ebb3f90a4b01c98eef53d

How could I get the same sorting behavior on equal points under any PHP version?

Comment: Which behaviour do you want? The one from PHP 5.6 or 7?

Comment: PHP's sorting functions are not stable, they don't specify the ordering of equal elements.

Comment: This is called undefined behavior. You should not rely on the order of two items if they are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have the same results in both versions, you will need to ensure that you specify how equal items will deal with other fields.

So you could solve this with...

```
usort($arr1, function ($a, $b) {
    if($a['points'] == $b['points']){
      return $a['date'] - $b['date'];
    }
    return ($a['points'] < $b['points']) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

So if the `points` value is the same, then use `date` as the differentiator (assuming a numeric comparison would work.)

Answer (score 2):

```
    $array = [
        ['points' => 10, 'date' => 3],
        ['points' => 10, 'date' => 2],
        ['points' => 10, 'date' => 1],
    ];

    usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
        if($a['points'] === $b['points']){
            return $b['date'] <=> $a['date'];
        }
        return $a['points'] <=> $b['points'];
    });

    var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the `<=>` operator is only PHP 7+, so will generate a syntax error in PHP 5.

Comment: Nonetheless, the essential idea here is correct:  you need to sort on *more than one key.*  When two values have the same `points` value, compare the `date`.  And also:  if all of the sort-key values in two records are the same, you should consider the final ordering to simply be, *"unpredictable."*

Comment: Yes, you're right @NigelRen. I was providing a solution for the PHP 7+ version. I am wondering how do we still talk about PHP version 5 nowadays... Anyway, ternary operators can be used instead of `<=>` as we all know :)

Answer (score 1):

As others have already noted, you need to sort on *more than one key.*  PHP provides for this through its `compare_func` callable, and it also provides the `<=>` *("spaceship") operator for your convenience in writing such functions.

If your `compare_func` finds that `points` is equal, it should proceed to compare `date` and so on, returning the first value that isn't zero.  *(You can use the `or` operator to do this.)*

And, if *all* of the sort-keys are equal, the behavior of `usort()` is "unpredictable."  In this case, you should not presume that the records will be presented in any particular order ... even from one call to `usort()` to the next.  If you think that "this version of PHP 'always' does it this way, and that version 'always' does it some other way," assume that you are merely mistaken.